SFML texture not displaying at the right location
I have a game in c++ using SFML library, if I press escape a menu should be drawn, for that i have a UI class, this class is drawn when I press escape so when the player opens the menu, for this UI i have a Button class that creates a button with a texture and a function to call when pressed, but my problem is that even though the button position is set to 0,0 the Sprite is somewhere around 200,200 but to call the function that the button should execute, I have to click at around 0,0? But the texture position isnt set to anything but the 0,0?
This is the button:
Button::Button(float x, float y, float wf, float hf, std::string path, std::function<void()> callback)
    : onClick(callback)
{
    if (!buttonTexture.loadFromFile(path))
    {
        std::cerr << "Error loading tilesheet from " << path << std::endl;
    }
    buttonSprite.setTexture(buttonTexture);
    buttonSprite.setPosition(0, 0);
    buttonSprite.setScale(wf, hf);
}

void Button::draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    window.draw(buttonSprite);
}

void Button::handleEvent(const sf::Event &event, const sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed)
    {
        if (event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left)
        {
            sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
            sf::FloatRect bounds = buttonSprite.getGlobalBounds();

            if (bounds.contains(static_cast<float>(mousePos.x), static_cast<float>(mousePos.y)))
            {
                if (onClick)
                {
                    onClick();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

and this is the Implementation in the UI.cpp

UI::UI(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    testButton = new Button(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, "res/Ships/PNGs/ship.png",
                            []()
                            {
                                std::cout << "Button clicked!" << std::endl;
                            });
}

and the button gets also updated and drawn:
 if (UItrue)
    {
        testButton->handleEvent(event, window);
    }

...


if (UItrue)
    {
        testButton->draw(window);
    }

the UI gets also updated and drawn in the main loop
I tried to print out the position of the buttonSprite but it said 0,0. Also the image I use for the button is currently the same as the players so I know its not because of that?
If you need further info or have any Ideas on why the sprite is offset please tell me.
Also if you want more of the code, I have it here on Github

Welcome to SO Abbadon! This sort of problem depends and your code looks good to me. Is your sprite consistently showing up at 200, 200 or is it random for each run. If so, you probably didn't define something. It is it consistent, take a look at the image you loaded into the sprite. If it is something like a png with a big section of background, that also could be your problem. Hope this helps!

Maybe this is related to origin. There is a function called setOrigin, check it out.

@Hudson, the sprite is at the same position everytime, its also not the image as I am using the same image as the player for now, but the setOrigin thing I can try!

The sprite appears offset because of the following two lines in your main.cpp:
view.setCenter(player.getPosition());
// or
view.setCenter(viewCenter);

You're changing the view to be centered around the player or the calculated viewCenter and you use the same view to also draw your UI, so your UI is also shifted by whatever amount the view has been shifted.
To adjust for this, you can use a separate view for the UI itself. See the [official tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.6/graphics-view.php#using-a-view on views.
Additionally, I highly recommend to no use global variables in your main.cpp. Eventually you'll run into crashes due to undefined behavior in the initialization/destruction order between your code and SFML's code. It also makes it a lot harder to understand your code flow, as global states can be changed at any time.
It's better to just use a "wrapper" class, that provides a defined scope for your shared variables.

Works! Thank you!
